# failed to install constraintlayout for android 1.0.2

Tags: android, sdk, android-constraintlayout

I am new to AndroidStudio and android programing please help me to solve my problem
when I create new project on AndroidStudio v3.1.4 frist time build is started to sync after 20 seconds build sync failed and show me this error :

> Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could
>   not resolve com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3.

and error:

> Unable to resolve dependency for
>   ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve
>   com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2.

and Such 5 more error...

I installed latest Sdk tools and Plugins..

I try to install constraintlayout for android  1.0.2 and solver for constraintlayout from SDK tools TAB on SDK manager Check that option then apply 
android studio start to download and installed and after 10 seconds say that installing finished!

This means that installed successfully But when I close that window show that those option early unchecked and show status "not installed"

Comment: Hi @mohsen, can you please upload the build.gradle file module and app level both or just checkout that you must have added the google repository in your app level gradle file

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. Turns out offline work for gradle was enabled for some reason. As such gradle is trying to get the version of constraint layout that is not cached to android studio. To enable offline work on android studio click File > Settings> Build Execution Deployment >Gradle. From there you can see a check box for offline work disable it. Hope this helps.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

this happens with last version update android, You can go back and make downgrade on packages gradle version or can, run clean builder, syncing again, if appear dependency offline from constraint, I did put here, to clean or to work offline. I don't remember now.

if you go to do the downgrade.

**Normal**
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc02'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'

**Downgrade**
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-rc01'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'

Comment: excuse me thanks for answer please explain what you say because i cant understand exactly what i should do now Point : my SDK Build tools version is 28.0.2 but i installed also ver 28.0.1 and 28.0.0rc02 and rc01 and 28.0.0 and 27.0.3  please help me to solve this error